# Opening help in a full window

Tags: vim

When I have no opened buffers, calling **:h** will open help in a split window. But I want it to open in a full-sized window. There doesn't see to be a *:nosplit* or *:full* command though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
:h | only
```

`:only` is the command that will make the current window the only window visible.

Comment: Hello!.  Thank you. One could use :only to expand but in the context of having more than one window previously open, how I can restore the layout (from showing only the expanded window to show all open windows as before executing :only)?  Thank you very much.

Comment: This will close other windows in the tab, so do not use this if you want to go back to a previously opened window (e.g., a file you wish to continue editing).

Comment: `command! -nargs=1 -complete=help H h <args> | only` .

Setting this in your .vimrc let's you use `:H` as you normally would `:h`, but already includes the `only` add-on.

Answer (score 28):

you can open a new tab just with the help with

```
:tab h
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll map this in my vimrc. (I was using a separate tab for the help file anyway).

Answer (score 9):

This admittedly hackish method should work for most terminal windows.  Tested in unix-flavored vim.

```
:set helpheight=99999
```

then

```
:h
```

Answer (score 8):

Two options:

You can switch to the other window and issue a "close window" command:

```
ctrl-W w  switches windows (to non-help window)
ctrl-W c  closes current window
```

... or you can open the help file directly.  On vim 7.3 for Windows (Cygwin), for example:

```
vim /usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/help.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add to your .vimrc or init.vim the following line:

```
augroup HelpBuffer | au! filetype help only | augroup END
```

It will create autogroup HelpBuffer and whenever a help buffer is opening `only` command is triggered and the buffer is widening.

Answer (score 3):

An awesome plugin for toggling windows fullscreen is [**vim-maximizer**](https://github.com/szw/vim-maximizer).

After it's installed you can simply use `<F3>` (default shortcut) to toggle fullscreen on the window.

You can also customize the shortcut keys, for example if you wanted to use `<C-w> z` (similar to tmux shortcut):

```
nnoremap <silent><C-w>z :MaximizerToggle<CR>
vnoremap <silent><C-w>z :MaximizerToggle<CR>gv
inoremap <silent><C-w>z <C-o>:MaximizerToggle<CR>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
command -nargs=? Help help <args> | only
```

You can add that to your `.vimrc`. Then write `:Help topic` to see help on a topic, and `:Help` to see help main page, both in full-sized windows.

Answer (score 2):

```
open vim from command line:  
lnx#> vim  
:help  
ctrl+w+shift+_ - will maximize window vertically.  
ctrl+w+| - will maximize window horizontally.
ctrl+w+= - will resize window to half size horizontally or vertically.
ctrl+w+(up or down) arrow will help to navigate into vertical windows.
ctrl+w+(left or right) arrow will help to navigate into horizontal windows.
```

NOTE: *Vim help documentation is wonderful!*

Maybe you'll enjoy also this: [Actually using ed - Arabesque](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/actually-using-ed/)

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with - it works with [Telescope](https://github.com/nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim)'s find help as well. It spawns the help file in a new tab, goes back to the previous one where it closes the opened split and goes back to the new tab with the help.
The second line lists the help file in the buffer list so it can appear in the [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline)'s tabline (bufferline):

```
augroup help_as_buffer
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType help :tabnew % | tabprevious | quit | tabnext 
  autocmd FileType help set buflisted
augroup END
```